# Не выводится значение в TextView

Tags: java, android

Что должно делать приложение: на данном этапе - вывести дату (при ее изменении) из `CalendarView` в `TextView`.

В чем проблема: Никаких ошибок при компиляции нет, однако, в самом приложении на телефоне при изменении даты на `CalendarView`, она не высвечивается на `TextView`.

Само приложение:

fragment_gallery.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
style="@style/CardView.Light"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/wallpaper"
tools:context=".ui.gallery.GalleryFragment">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_gallery"
    android:layout_width="259dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="@string/vvod"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<CalendarView
    android:id="@+id/calendarView"
    style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.CalendarView"
    android:layout_width="374dp"
    android:layout_height="308dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="23dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="23dp"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    android:focusedMonthDateColor="@color/colorAccent"
    android:showWeekNumber="true"
    android:unfocusedMonthDateColor="#FF5722"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="56dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="476dp"
    android:text="@string/vv"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

GalleryFragment.java:

```
package com.example.beecalc.ui.gallery;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CalendarView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders;

import com.example.beecalc.R;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class GalleryFragment extends Fragment {
CalendarView cal;
private GalleryViewModel galleryViewModel;

public View onCreateView(@NonNull final LayoutInflater inflater,
                         final ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    galleryViewModel =
            ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(GalleryViewModel.class);
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gallery, container, false);
    final View i = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gallery, container, false);
    final TextView textView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_gallery);
    galleryViewModel.getText().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {
            textView.setText("Дата готовых маток:");
            final  TextView text_gallery = (TextView) i.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
            final CalendarView calendarView = i.findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
            calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSelectedDayChange(@NonNull CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                    DateFormat TIMESTAMP = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                    String s = String.format("%04d.%02d.%02d", year, month + 1, dayOfMonth);
                    text_gallery.setText(s);

                }
            });
        }

    });
    return root;
}

}
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, спасибо заранее!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Удалите этот код:

```
galleryViewModel.getText().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {
        textView.setText("Дата готовых маток:");
        final  TextView text_gallery = (TextView) i.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        final CalendarView calendarView = i.findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
        calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSelectedDayChange(@NonNull CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                DateFormat TIMESTAMP = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                String s = String.format("%04d.%02d.%02d", year, month + 1, dayOfMonth);
                text_gallery.setText(s);

            }
        });
    }

});
```

И добавьте этот в `onViewCreated`:

```
textView.setText("Дата готовых маток:");
calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSelectedDayChange(@NonNull CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
        DateFormat TIMESTAMP = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String s = String.format("%04d.%02d.%02d", year, month + 1, dayOfMonth);
        text_gallery.setText(s);
    }
});
```

И этот в `onCreateView`:

```
text_gallery = (TextView) i.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
calendarView = i.findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
```

Заранее объявив вне методов:

```
final  TextView text_gallery;
final CalendarView calendarView;
```

**Update:**

Ахахах, кажется я нашел Вашу ошибку:

```
View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gallery, container, false);
final View i = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gallery, container, false);
```

Вы используете для своих действий `i`. А потом возвращаете `root`. Удалите строчку с `i`. И используйте везде вместо него `root`.

Comment: Все также не работает....

Comment: @C1oud поставьте, пожалуйста, точку останова на любой строке внутри `onSelectedDayChange` и проверьте, вызывается ли он вообще.

Comment: @C1oud кроме того немного исправил ответ

Comment: @C1oud кажется, я понял, откуда была проблема, добавил update в ответ

Comment: @C1oud я не уверен. Я точно знаю, что предложенный вариант правильный. На счет Вашего - просто не уверен)